# Timer Not Stopping when UIImage gets to a certain point

Tags: uiimage, nstimer

I am developing an app where the menu move away to reveal a second menu. I am moving the image with a NSTimer, and want it to stop when the image hits a certain coordinate on the screen. But what I am currently using is not working, it is moving the image, but it doesn't stop. What am I doing wrong? EDIT: This is Xcode 5

```
- (IBAction)showSubMenu:(id)sender {

moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(moveMenus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self stopMovement];


}

-(void)stopMovement {
if (mainMenu.center.y < -160) {
    [moveTimer invalidate];
    moveTimer = nil;
}

}


-(void)moveMenus {
mainMenu.center = (CGPointMake(mainMenu.center.x, mainMenu.center.y-1));
goButton.center = (CGPointMake(goButton.center.x, goButton.center.y-1));
Info.center = (CGPointMake(Info.center.x, Info.center.y-1));
helpButton.center = (CGPointMake(helpButton.center.x, helpButton.center.y-1));

subMenu.center = (CGPointMake(subMenu.center.x, subMenu.center.y-1));
description.center = (CGPointMake(description.center.x, description.center.y-1));
playEndless.center = (CGPointMake(playEndless.center.x, playEndless.center.y-1));
playQuick.center = (CGPointMake(playQuick.center.x, playQuick.center.y-1));
playSoundboard.center = (CGPointMake(playSoundboard.center.x, playSoundboard.center.y-1));
confirm.center = (CGPointMake(confirm.center.x, confirm.center.y-1));

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!
Rafee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `stopMovement` every time your view move, so change your code like this :

```
- (IBAction)showSubMenu:(id)sender 
{
    moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(moveMenus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopMovement 
{
    if (mainMenu.center.y < -160) 
    {
        [moveTimer invalidate];
        moveTimer = nil;
    }
}


- (void)moveMenus 
{
    mainMenu.center = (CGPointMake(mainMenu.center.x, mainMenu.center.y-1));
    goButton.center = (CGPointMake(goButton.center.x, goButton.center.y-1));
    Info.center = (CGPointMake(Info.center.x, Info.center.y-1));
    helpButton.center = (CGPointMake(helpButton.center.x, helpButton.center.y-1));

    subMenu.center = (CGPointMake(subMenu.center.x, subMenu.center.y-1));
    description.center = (CGPointMake(description.center.x, description.center.y-1));
    playEndless.center = (CGPointMake(playEndless.center.x, playEndless.center.y-1));
    playQuick.center = (CGPointMake(playQuick.center.x, playQuick.center.y-1));
    playSoundboard.center = (CGPointMake(playSoundboard.center.x, playSoundboard.center.y-1));
    confirm.center = (CGPointMake(confirm.center.x, confirm.center.y-1));

    // Call here
    [self stopMovement];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll Accept the answer in 5 minutes (Very Quick response)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to validate the answer if it's helpful for you :)